# How to specify build command when enabling automatic deployment to Heroku from Github in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, heroku

I'm building a Spring Boot application and planning to host it on Heroku with automatic deployments from Github repository. However, the application has different URLs for accessing MySQL database in dev and prod environments. therefore I'm planning to create 2 files named `application-dev.properties`,`application-prod.properties` and place relevant configuration there. Now I want to specify the build command to use `application-prod.properties` on Heroku upon automatic deployments. How can I do that? Is **only pushing `application-prod.properties` to Github so Heroku chooses it as default and I won't need to modify Heroku build command** a good idea?

Comment: Add an environment var in your Heroku app's config screen: name: `spring.profiles.active`, value = `prod`. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#managing-config-vars

Comment: Additionally, Spring profile profiles are resolved at runtime and not build time so the Heroku build command does into come into it.